# Get First and Last Related Object for Django Rest API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have Django Rest API serializers based on 2 models, Book and Chapter

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    published_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)

class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='chapters', db_index=True
    )
    published_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)
```

In the Book serializer I want 2 custom fields

- `first_chapter`
- `last_chapter`

Each having objects of model `Chapter` as you can understand from the field name first and last objects order by `published_at` field

The Chapter model has a Foreign Key to Book.

I tried something like below to get the last chapter

```py
class LastChapterField(serializers.RelatedField):
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return core_models.Chapter.objects\
            .filter(book=M.OuterRef("pk"))\
            .select_related("number")\
            .order_by("-published_at")[:1]
```

But I don't see the last chapter included in my results even though it is explicitly mentioned in `fields` of Book Serializer

I want the complete object in returning result and I want to be able to use order by on one of these nested fields (first_chapter or last_chapter) of `Chapter` model object.

Comment: can you show me the models

Comment: @TanveerAhmad edited the original post

Comment: oh got it. first, you will get it using the reverse relationship..! and the second one is using serializermethodfield..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KqhBkMv7aM&t=628s&ab_channel=PrettyPrinted 
you will get it reverse relationship example from that link.
if you didn't get it let me know.

Comment: @TanveerAhmad I put the query as return value for the field I created: `last_chapter = serializers.SerializerMethodField()`
Giving error: Object of type Chapter is not JSON serializable

Comment: Also please remember that I want to be able to sort data using one of these first_chapter or last_chapter nested fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) that will retrieve the objects you want and use an other serializer in it:

```py
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers


class ChapterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Chapter
        fields = ('published_at', 'modified_at', 'added_at',)


class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_chapter = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    last_chapter = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_first_chapter(self, instance):
        return ChapterSerializer(instance.chapters.order_by('published_at').first()).data

    def get_last_chapter(self, instance):
        return ChapterSerializer(instance.chapters.order_by('published_at').last()).data

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('first_chapter', 'last_chapter',
                  [...]  # Add the other fields you want to display here
                 )
```

Then you can use your serializer in your views, e.g.:

```py
# views.py
from .serializers import BookSerializer
from .models import Book
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView


class BookRetrieveView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

Comment: Does this not work with viewsets.ModelViewSet?
I'm still seeing Object of type ChapterSerializer is not JSON serializable

Comment: @yashas123 ah yes sorry, you need to return  `serializer(...).data`, not just `serializer(...)`. I updated my answer.

Comment: That worked, one last thing, how to sort data using fields under `last_chapter`